# jQuery: unwrap element in HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory

http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/vZLnr/

I'm trying to find the best way to unwrap an HTML string (like AJAX response), without first attaching it to the document.  Also, which is the best for memory management?

#### HTML

- ```
  <div class="label">Start With:</div>
  <pre id="original"></pre>

  <div class="label">What's Wanted:</div>
  <pre id="wanted"><div>foo</div><div>bar</div></pre>

  <hr />

  <div class="label">Attempt: .find()</div>
  <pre id="find"></pre>

  <div class="label">Attempt: .closest()</div>
  <pre id="closest"></pre>
  ```

#### CSS

- ```
  .label    { font       : italic bold 11px Georgia;   margin    : 1em 0 .5em; }
  pre       { border     : 1px solid black;            padding   : 1em;        }
  hr        { margin     : 1.5em 0 1em; }

  #original { background : #eee; }
  #wanted   { background : #def; }
  ```

#### JavaScript

- ```
     var $html= "<pre><div>foo</div></pre><pre><div>bar</div></pre>";

     // No Changes
     jQuery('#original').html($html);


     // Find
     var $find = jQuery($html).find('*').unwrap();
     jQuery('#find').html($find);


     // Closest
     var $closest = jQuery($html).closest('pre').unwrap().html();
     jQuery('#closest').html($closest);


     // Wrapped
     var $pre = jQuery('pre', jQuery($html).wrap('<div />').parent() );
     $pre.each(function(){
                  jQuery('#wrapped').append(jQuery(this).html());
              });

     //=========== Prettify Output ===========
     var $wanted = jQuery('#wanted').html();
     jQuery('pre').not('#wanted, #original, #original *')
                  .each(function(){
                    var t = jQuery(this);
                    t.css({background: t.html()==$wanted?'#efe':'#fee'});
                  });
  ```

---

#### Edit

1. *The `.find()` method needs some work as it removes the white space containers. Imagine `<pre><span>Code</span> <span>Here</span></pre>`, which would turn into `<span>Code</span><span>Here</span>` (dropped whitespace).*

Comment: Do you want to unwrap just the outer tag, or a specific type of tag?

Comment: The outer tag, but it'd be nice to be able to select the type of outer tag, in case there is something like `<pre>foo</pre><div>bar</div><span>foobar</span>` (many outer tags and any order) and you only wanted to remove the div.

Comment: The original problem was only for one outer tag (eg `<pre>...</pre>`), but I like to be more robust.

Answer (score 1):

One generalizable way to unwrap it would be to simply traverse the string, either for the outermost tag or for a specific tag, adding each character that isn't part of the tag to a new string (once you hit a <, check the whole tag). Once it's found, start a counter at 0 and continue traversing the string until its closing tag is found, adding each character to the new string. If at this point the counter is 0, skip the tag and add the rest of the original string to the new string. Any time you encounter an opening tag of any kind, add one to the counter. Any closing tags, subtract 1 (so you dont end up removing the closing tag from a nested tag).

I can't really speak to memory management, as I am unfamiliar with how javascript manages memory.

I hope I have been of some help.

Comment: Yes, the count approach could work, but it would mean I'd need an XHTML regex parser, which I would like to avoid doing :)  Regarding memory management, I'm just curious if there would be any footprint if I deleted the variable (eg `$find`), I'm not sure how jQuery is releasing their internals.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what your actual question is, but I can forsee two possible difficulties.

1. `.html()` only returns the *inner contents* of a set of HTML elements, not the tag itself
2. `.find()` only searches descendent nodes, not the supplied node.

Both of those issues can be resolved by adding an extra tag around your HTML before calling those methods.

**EDIT** I *think* what you're after is this:

```
jQuery($html).filter('pre').children('div').appendTo('#wanted');
```

The `.filter()` line works on the top level elements, not on their descendents.

The elements aren't added into the real DOM until the `.appendTo()` method is invoked.

Comment: You are right on both points, which is what I've done in my example.  `find('*')` will find get all the immediate children and then unwrap the parent, which is what we want.  On the other hand the `wrapped` example is using the selector/context approach, which is why we had to first `wrap()` then point to that's `parent()`.  `html()` is sort of like the reverse unwrap (instead of unwrapping the parent of an element, we can use it to unwrap the selected element).

Comment: What I was really hoping to find was something similar to `closest()`, but instead of returning one element, it would turn an array of all the elements.  Essentially, it'd be like find, but it would start with the current element and all its the siblings.

Comment: No, I meant wrap a single element around the _whole_ HTML - you have a `<pre>` around _each_ topmost element in the HTML.  See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/BBegB/ where there's only a single `<pre>` tag.

Comment: :Alnitak: right, but if you looked at my `wrapped` example, you'll notice I put a `div` around the whole HTML.

Comment: @vol7ron sure, but why put both those pre tags there in the first place? you're still being incredibly unclear about what you exactly want, and why the version I've posted doesn't achieve that.

Comment: Sometimes you can't control the [client]input, which is what you did; however, instead of modifying the output from server, which is where the string is created, instead my `wrapped` example shows how to modify the input from the client-side.  In initial testing, I was using a string similar to your fiddle, thinking I'd have something like an XML document, but now I'm thinking about places where I'm retrieving parts of documents.  So the clarity is only in the example of what it's **Start With:**, and **What's Wanted:**

Comment: My question has less to do with code that works (as mine works as expected) and more to do with if there's a better way to do it, or if there any performance implications, as well as how jQuery handles the processes in memory.  --- Thanks a bunch for the effort